# Switching the Data source in a Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi

I have an Existing report in Power BI with Oracle Data Source from which I had directly access the Table.

But now I need to Change the Data Source of the Report using SSAS.

By Using SSAS, we can access the oracle Tables and deploy the SSAS in Azure Service.

Now through this Azure Service we can access the Data.

My Question is Without any Changes in the Report, Can we Simply Change the DataSource? Because I'm Showing Lot of Graphs in that Report.

Since I'm New to Power BI , Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, as long as the underlying source data tables are exactly the same, you can just go into the Power BI data model and just change the source.

Comment: Its not that simple, because you are not only changing the data source, but also its type (Oracle->SSAS) and storage mode (DQ->Live connection). You will have to at least manually change the M code. Definitely it will be easier to redo the report from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will likely be an unpredictably large amount of other issues (character encoding, date formatting, etc.) that you'll have to work through.

The way I might approach this problem is, if the tables are exactly identical, or you didn't make any changes within power query (like removing columns, merging tables, etc.) you may be able to modify the M code within the advanced editor, and try to swap the data sources to see if it works.

1. Go into "Transform Data"
2. Select the table you want to modify
3. Click the "Advanced Editor" icon in the ribbon.
   [image]
4. Here, I imported an excel file, but for you, it should show some kind of "AnalysisServices" line. I don't have an SSAS database to connect to so I can't validate. Try replacing this line with the connection string to your SSAS datasource and see if it works.
   [image]
5. Save, apply update, and see if it works?
   [image]

Again, this is not really advisable, but if you want to give it a try, and the data sources are identical, this is how I might approach the problem before just re-making the report whole-cloth.